# How to access files through pydrive or other alternative of pydrive

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to run this github code but i am confused how they are reading data from google drive and what is id representing there ..

https://github.com/janerjzou/AD_FL_DL/blob/main/Federated%20Model.ipynb

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

id = '1rxgk3e9O4doAoEFN3BeZqKULqGl7j6yV'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Device #1.csv')   # Device #1

id = '1YXc02xvqULO0uUP7xcb4W84SV6RxruoN'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Device #2.csv')   # Device #2

id = '1NZL4v46VhdSKmF2NKAYdWIQ0yGmh4Aic'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Device #3.csv')   # Device #3
```

Comment: id is google drive file id: in google drive, each file have an unique id to identify them (e.g.: those alphanumeric string in url when sharing those files)